# Is it bad practice to run `net start "<service name>"` on an already running service (or a service whose status I don't check beforehand)?

Tags: windows, powershell, service

**Disclaimer** I'm not familiar with these subjects (services, `net` command, and server maintenance in general).

On Windows, the `net` command allows to stop and start services, via `net stop "<service name>"` and `net start "<service name>"`

Is it bad practice to run `net start "<service name>"` on a service whose status is not checked beforehand?

I understand that I could check the service status, and start it only if the status is `stopped`. But if this is not necessary, why complicate things?

I did try to run the command on an already running service, and Powershell simply responded `Le service demandé a déjà été démarré.` which might translate to `The requested service has already been started.` I did not see any bad side effects, but I might overlook a lot of issues.

Use case would be to make sure that a specific service is indeed running.

This specific service is supposed to start automatically. The server that hosts it is configured to reboot every day at a specific time (I have no way to control this), and on some occasions, the service does not automatically start. So while we are investigating the starting issue, I want to temporarily fix this by automatically (via the task scheduler) starting the service at a certain time after the reboot if it is not already running.

Comment: [1] from what i can tell, there is no disadvantage to using `net start` on an already-started service. ///// [2] powershell has a cmdlet to get info about a service. take a look at  >>> `Get-Help Get-Service -Full` <<< for some ideas on how to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's absolutely ok to launch net start ... without checking, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any negative outcomes of attempting to start a service that's already started. Yes, it's fine.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Use case would be to make sure that a specific service is indeed running.

If the service is providing a function or purpose, that would be the test. Otherwise, the service needs to report status correctly - which it currently is not.

Comment: I realize my title could be misleading, it is corrected now. The service can report its status just fine. It is only I who don't want to check its status before running the `net start` command. I wonder if it is a bad practice, or if it is a shortcut that is perfectly fine to take.